# how to implement JMS on Android project

Tags: java, android, jms, openjms

Currently, i'm working on android project. I have to join a jms server based on openJMS.

i've not found any library, anyone know how to implement JMS client on Android ?

thx.

Comment: I doubt it's possible. There is no support for the `javax.*` packages in Dalvik. Have you considered using a mediator? You could set up a server-side application using a more Android-friendly API to communicate with mobile clients and JMS to communicate with your actual server.

Answer (score 2):

Use the Kaazing WebSocket Gateway Android JMS Client API

you can visit Kaazing official website for that.

Thanks!

Comment: Link-only answers are deprecated

Answer (score 0):

We have also faced same scenario.

You can use the Kaazing WebSocket Gateway to connect Android (and other) clients to JMS over WebSocket

- [Checklist: Build Android JMS Clients](https://kaazing.com/doc/5.0/jms_client_docs/dev-android/o_dev_android.html).